# Alternative to Luasocket for web requests using system proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, lua

I already had 2 questions regarding Lua and web requests but I am still struggling.

I still need to download a file by url and thanks to Paul Kulchenko I figured out what the main reason is for my initial failure: the corporate network I am in blocks outgoing request, probably a DMZ, Firewall or whatever a company uses. Using one of the company proxies should solve my issues but it does not.

Here is the code I am using:

```
-- retrieve the content of a URL
local socket = require("socket")
local http = require("socket.http")
local inspect = require("inspect")
--http.PROXY = "http://my.company.proxy.com:8080"
--http.PROXY = "http://my.company.proxy.com:8080"
--http.PROXY = "http://my.company.proxy.com:8080"
http.PROXY = "http://my.company.proxy.com:8080"
local body, code = http.request("http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CCROQ8vUEAEgFke.jpg")
print(inspect(code))
if not body then error(code) end

-- save the content to a file
local f = assert(io.open('test.jpg', 'wb'))
f:write(body)
f:close()
```

All errors I get with the above code are timeouts (credit to Paul).

Using this script I get different errors but nonetheless errors..

```
local http = require("socket.http")
local socket = require("socket")
local inspect = require("inspect")
require("show")
require("ltn12")
local ResFileStr = "CCROQ8vUEAEgFke.jpg"
local PathStr = "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/"
local ResHnd, ErrStr = io.open(ResFileStr, "wb")
if ResHnd then
  local Req = {
  url = PathStr .. ResFileStr,
  sink = ltn12.sink.file(ResHnd),
  --proxy = "http://my.company.proxy.com:8080"
  --proxy = "http://my.company.proxy.com:8080"
  --proxy = "http://my.company.proxy.com:8080"
  --proxy = "http://my.company.proxy.com:8080"
  proxy = "http://my.company.proxy.com:8080"
  }
  local Response = {http.request(Req)}
  ObjectShow(Response, "Response")
  print(inspect(Response))
else
io.write("Error opening ", ResFileStr, " for writing\n")
end
```

The errors I get are either 500 Domain not found or 404 Not found.

When I use Microsofts .NET framework with System.net.WebClient class there are no problems with downloading the file or accessing the website. Unfortunately I don't know what Microsofts class does differently so I guess it is more high-level code using my system setting for the proxy.

So, my question is: are there similar "high-level" libraries or other libraries I could use except for Luasocket? I took a look at libcurl, luacurl but they seem to be even more complicated to use than luasocket. Or just any other way I could get this working with lua? Or is my lua approach completely wrong?

PS. `inspect` is a library by kikito (can be found on github for debugging) and `show` is just this script with this function

```
function ObjectShow(Val, Key, TruncLen)
print(Key, Val)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Lua-cURL](https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3) library.

Code not tested because I have no proxy

```
local cURL = require "cURL"

local f = assert(io.open('test.jpg', 'wb'))

cURL.easy{
  url           = "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CCROQ8vUEAEgFke.jpg",
  proxy         = "http://my.company.proxy.com:8080",
  writefunction = f
}
:perform()
:close()

f:close()
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try that on Monday. Do you maybe have an other idea what I could try? Other lib?

Comment: can you provide me with a dl link for the lua-curl? I cant download it using lua rocks (failed to fetch manifest) and downloading it directly from github also does not work.